# How to list file sizes under random folders?

Tags: linux, centos

I have a directories like below and what I want to list is all ".Trash" folder sizes. Is there any way to list these folder sizes?

```
mailboxes/ronaldo/maildir/.Trash/....
mailboxes/user.one/maildir/.Trash/....
mailboxes/messi/maildir/.Trash/....
mailboxes/user.two/maildir/.Trash/....
```

I want to get all user's .Trash folder sizes.

Comment: `du mailboxes/*/*/.Trash` or better to sum them `du -s mailboxes/*/*/.Trash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   du -sh <folder-path>
```

for the above case folder path is " `mailboxes/*/*/.Trash` "

Comment: There are a number of useful options that can help tailor its use to meet your needs. Specifically the `-d` and `-c` options can compute total by subdirectory -- useful in many circumstances.